# Facebook app using ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to create a Facebook app using default Facebook Template for Asp.Net MVC. I'm registered  in developers.facebook.com and created an app.

I've created the ASP.NET based MVC webpage using following steps:

1. I've enabled the SSL property to True.
2. Copied the SSL URL (in my case it was localhost:44301).
3. In Solution Explorer, right clicked the MvcFBTestApp and select Properties.
4. Select the Web tab. Paste the SSL URL into the Project Url box, then click Create Virtual
   Directory.
5. I've used the App ID/App Secret and Namespace of facebook App and configured the web.config file of my MVCApp with these settings.
6. Saved the project and Run the project.

Now if I run the app it request for Facebook login and logs in to facebook. But after that it generates following error instead of showing default MVC webpage. Appreciate if anyone can give me guidance.

**Server Error in '/' Application.**

---

Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.

Source Error: 
An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[JsonReaderException: Could not convert string to integer: public_profile. Path 'data[0].permission', line 1, position 39.]
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsInt32Internal() +921
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsInt32() +39
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) +228
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateDictionary(IWrappedDictionary wrappedDictionary, JsonReader reader, JsonDictionaryContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id) +1469
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +866
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +184
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(IWrappedCollection wrappedList, JsonReader reader, JsonArrayContract contract, JsonProperty containerProperty, String id) +1180
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, Object existingValue, String id) +698
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +233
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(JsonProperty property, JsonConverter propertyConverter, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerProperty, JsonReader reader, Object target) +598
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(Object newObject, JsonReader reader, JsonObjectContract contract, JsonProperty member, String id) +1799
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +517
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, JsonContract contract, JsonProperty member, JsonContainerContract containerContract, JsonProperty containerMember, Object existingValue) +184
   Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent) +740
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +1143
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType) +47
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings) +193
   Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type) +44
   Facebook.FacebookClient.ProcessResponse(HttpHelper httpHelper, String responseString, Type resultType, Boolean containsEtag, IList`1 batchEtags) +2070
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Api(HttpMethod httpMethod, String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) +1168
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters, Type resultType) +52
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path, Object parameters) +139
   Facebook.FacebookClient.Get(String path) +100
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Client.FacebookClientExtensions.GetCurrentUserPermissions(FacebookClient client) +74
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Providers.DefaultFacebookPermissionService.GetUserPermissions(String userId, String accessToken) +217
   Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Facebook.Authorization.FacebookAuthorizeFilter.OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) +5182
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAuthorizationFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) +143
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__1e(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +978
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +523
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +83
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +501
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +417
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +127
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +161
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +92
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout) +97
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate endDelegate, Object tag) +53
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +373
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +88
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +50
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +301
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Thanks & BR,

Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

This a parsing problem inside the Newtonsoft.Json library. Some string can't be parsed into an integer.

Try to ensure that you are installing the latest updated version of the Newtonsoft.Json library.